# how to disable or remove css media queries with jquery

Tags: jquery, media-queries

i'm working on a specific page within my site that should not be responsive.  the rest of the site should be (and currently is) responsive.

due to limitations of this project, i cannot serve an alternate stylesheet.  therefore, it would be ideal to remove or exclude all media queries that live in my stylesheet via jquery for this page.

i'm thinking there must be a way via jquery to look inside my stylesheet for

```
@media only screen and (max-width: whatever) { }
```

and comment out or remove those lines when loading this page only.

i had a look at [Can all media queries be overriden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148836/can-all-media-queries-be-overriden) which is similar to what i'm looking to do, but due to limitations i can't add classes to the body or revise all existing media queries to be prefixed like that.

please let me know if you folks have any creative ideas here, as it's a bit of a challenge to say the least!

thank you!

Comment: You're in quite a pickle then.

Comment: Put them in a separate stylesheet. Remove the stylesheet from the DOM.

Comment: not sure why i didn't think of this - thanks!!