# How to disable all media query from mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a website and i want to **disable media query** when i click a button `View Desktop` from `moblie view`.  How to disable media query from mobile site.
        These are my media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:900px) and (max-width:1024px)
{

}
```

Comment: Please understand my question first.

Comment: sorry, is this website in php or pure html

Comment: Look at this answer first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148836/can-all-media-queries-be-overriden

Comment: its about bootstrap but may be it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device

Comment: You can swap the css files dynamically with Jquery. So why not create a css file without any media queries and dynamically load it to the DOM when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move all media queries to a separate css file (ex. mobile.css) and on button click disable this file.

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){
    $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="mobile.css"]').attr('disabled', 'true');
});
```

Hope this helps